# Need code for putting a slider (short code) and static image side by side on home page in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, slider, alignment

I have created a slider in creely that is 300x300 it is a shortcode and then I have an image also 300x300 that I want to put next to it so they are side by side on my home page in Wordpress.  I have tried putting them in a table and also putting them in columns (by using insert shortcode in text editor) and inserting the items in those but nothing is working.  They only stack on top of each other.  Any help on what coding I should use and where to put the coding would be appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately without actual HTML and CSS there isn't much that we can help you with. Can you post a very small snippet of code?

Comment: I went to W3school and looked up how to align 3 images and it told me to put this HTML
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="img_snow.jpg" alt="Snow" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="img_forest.jpg" alt="Forest" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="img_mountains.jpg" alt="Mountains" style="width:100%">
  </div>
</div>

and then it said to add this CSS:
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  padding: 5px;
}

.row::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

Comment: So i put the HTML on my page and then put the CSS in my additional css file within woocommerce?  I don't know where I should put all this, like what goes where?  After I find that out I can modify to only have two columns.  Another question is can i put a short code (the slider) as content in one of the columns?  Hope this helps.